# JSONP: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have this code. I am using the [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp/issues) library in my React-Redux app.

```
export function fetchAirBnbData() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    fetchJsonp('http://assets.airbnb.com/frontend/search_results.js', {
     jsonpCallback: 'search_results',
   })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
      }).then(function (json) {
       console.log('parsed json', json)
       dispatch(loadAirBnBData(json))
      }).catch(function (ex) {
       console.log('parsing failed', ex)
     })
 }
}
```

I am getting this error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: search_results is not defined`

From what I know, this should work. Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Is it possible that you need () after search_results

Comment: @ModarNa No because this is a string of the callback function, not the function itself.

Comment: From the documentation i see they are calling a .jsonp file can this be the issue

Comment: The extension is irrelevant. It should work as long as the output is JSONP. See this example which uses `aspx` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `fetch-jsonp`, you should use

```
fetchJsonp('http://assets.airbnb.com/frontend/search_results.js', {
  jsonpCallbackFunction: 'search_results',
})
```